# What information Google Sheets requires for ACTION_VIEW?

Tags: android-studio, google-sheets

My app created an Excel file that can be opened by Google Sheets and MS-Excel. But when I opened it by using ACTION_VIEW via my app, the Excel file couldn't be viewed by Google Sheets but it worked fine with MS-Excel. When viewing the file by Google Sheet, it showed a message *"Google Sheets was unable to open your spreadsheet"*.

I've tried clearing all data from the Excel file and only viewed the empty file but still got this problem with Google Sheets.

```
Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(dbActivity.getApplicationContext(),"com.aaa.fileprovider", createdFile);
dbActivity.getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(dbActivity.getPackageName(), data, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
dbActivity.getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(dbActivity.getPackageName(), data, FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
Intent openIntent = new Intent();
openIntent.setType(applicationType);
openIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
openIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
openIntent.setData(data);
openIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data);
try {
    dbActivity.startActivity(openIntent);
}
catch (Exception ex){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(dbActivity, "No applications to open the file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

Most people don't have MS-Excel on their phone, so I want my app able to view created file by Google Sheets

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Google Sheets requires you to set both data and MIME type on the ACTION_VIEW intent.

Replace this:

```
openIntent.setData(data);
```

With this:

```
openIntent.setDataAndType(data, mimeType)
```

Where `mimeType` is the MIME type of the file you're sending - e.g., "text/csv".

Comment: Oh God, thank you very much for this. I have spent several hours searching on how to fix this Google Sheets error.
Btw, do you know any official documentation about this?

Comment: Only the docs for the Intent method. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setDataAndType(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String) 
Google sheets doesn't have any docs on this. I think a possible issue is that the file you create in your app doesn't have the proper MIME type, so you need to set it explicitly through the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line; it will work:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```